# Python error arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hello I have the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = int(input("lenght of t and b.  m = "))

t = 27 * np.random.random( (m, 1) )
b = 27 * np.random.random( (m, 1) )

A = np.ones( (m, 1) )  
A = np.hstack( (A, t) )

x = np.linalg.solve( np.dot(A.T, A), np.dot(A.T, b) ) 
print("x = \n", x) 

t1 = np.linspace ( min(t), max(t), 50) 
b1 = np.polyval(x[::-1, t1]) 
plt.plot(t1, b1)

plt.plot(t, b, "ro")
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("b")
plt.show()
```

I'm trying to do a plot but i'm getting the following error "IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"
At the line:

```
b1 = np.polyval(x[::-1, t1])
```

How can I solve this please?

Comment: You did not tell us what you want to achieve with this line. Maybe it is just a typo for `np.polyval(x[::-1], t1)`, we don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this:

b1 = np.polyval(x[::-1] ,t1)

Answer (score 1):

This error may also happen when the DataFrame or numpy array has NaN values. It can be fixed like this:

```
df.fillna(0)
```

Or any other suitable `fillna()` strategy